# No Admin controls for file manager - refuses admin control for others

Tags: software-installation, root

I'm wanting my money back. This Elementary OS refuses any sort of admin controls to copy files for theming. I've used other file managers as well. Can't install gksu/gksudo, can't edit with gedit. The whole system is locked down to basic. Not what interests me.

Comment: If you right click on the Files app, and select 'New Windows as Administator' and then input your password, does it work?